# android- How to make screen helpers

Tags: android, android-button

I've seen  this in lots of applications , when you open the application for the first time, to shows a semi transparent screen and mark a tools and shows some description about it .

like this :

[image]

as you can see,it marks an icon on menu and shows some text about it and there is a button at the end of the page .

How can I make something like this ?

Comment: Something like this?  https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView

Comment: Alternatively, there's a long list of similar examples.  https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198

Comment: Glad to help you happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to get [Showcase](https://github.com/wanelo/android-tutorial)

```
View showcasedView = findViewById(R.id.view_to_showcase);
ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(showcasedView);
ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(target, this, R.string.showcase_title, R.string.showcase_details);
```

OR you can try with [TourGuide](https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide)